# Vectorizing with multidplyr does not render the correct output

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, multidplyr

I tried to parallelize `ape::dist_topo()`, a function to compute distances between unrooted trees.

Normally the function works like this (reprex: 4 random trees with 5 leaves each):

```
library(tidyverse)
# devtools::install_github("hadley/multidplyr")
library(multidplyr)
library(ape)
set.seed(3)

trees <- 
  map(rep(5, 4), rtree) %>% 
  do.call(c.phylo, .) %>% # To transform my list of phylo objects in a multiPhylo object
  unroot.multiPhylo()

dist.topo(trees)
#      tree1 tree2 tree3
# tree2     4            
# tree3     4     2      
# tree4     4     4     2
```

I created a function to compute distances 2 by 2 in a data.frame (in order to split in clusters by rows):

```
dist.topo2 <- function(multiphylo){
  expand.grid(multiphylo, multiphylo) %>% 
    as.tibble() %>% 
    mutate(dist = map2(Var1, Var2, dist.topo)) %>% 
    pull(dist) %>% 
    matrix(., nrow = sqrt(length(.))) %>% 
    as.dist()
}

dist.topo2(trees)
#   1 2 3
# 2 4    
# 3 4 2  
# 4 4 4 2
```

As expected, the result is the same (regardless the names).

Then I added the `multidplyr::partition()` and `multidplyr::collect()` functions in my pipeline:

```
dist.topo3 <- function(multiphylo){
  expand.grid(multiphylo, multiphylo) %>% 
    as.tibble() %>% 
    partition() %>%
    mutate(dist = purrr::map2(Var1, Var2, ape::dist.topo)) %>% 
    collect() %>%
    pull(dist) %>% 
    matrix(., nrow = sqrt(length(.))) %>% 
    as.dist()
}

dist.topo3(trees)
#   1 2 3
# 2 4    
# 3 0 4  
# 4 2 4 4
# Warning messages:
# 1: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#   Vectorizing 'multiPhylo' elements may not preserve their attributes
# 2: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#   Vectorizing 'multiPhylo' elements may not preserve their attributes
# 3: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#   Vectorizing 'multiPhylo' elements may not preserve their attributes
# 4: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#   Vectorizing 'multiPhylo' elements may not preserve their attributes
# 5: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#   Vectorizing 'multiPhylo' elements may not preserve their attributes
# 6: In bind_rows_(x, .id) :
#   Vectorizing 'multiPhylo' elements may not preserve their attributes
```

As you can see, the distances are different whereas the operations didn't change.

How can I fix that ? Maybe it's not possible ([See here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2457))

Thanks

Note: I'm aware that this solution could be non-optimal (especially because it computes each distance two times) but it's not the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `partition` will shard the data.frame randomly and `collect` will unshard the data.frame randomly. If you add the row number as a column and arrange after collecting, it fixes the issue

```
dist.topo3 <- function(multiphylo){
  expand.grid(multiphylo, multiphylo) %>% 
    as.tibble() %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    partition(rn) %>%
    mutate(dist = purrr::map2(Var1, Var2, ape::dist.topo)) %>% 
    collect() %>%
    arrange(rn) %>%
    pull(dist) %>% 
    matrix(., nrow = sqrt(length(.))) %>% 
    as.dist()
}
dist.topo3(trees)
#   1 2 3
# 2 4    
# 3 4 2  
# 4 4 4 2
```

Answer (score 4):

I would rather use package {furrr} than {multidplyr}:

```
library(furrr)
plan(multiprocess)

dist.topo4 <- function(multiphylo) {

  dists <- expand.grid(multiphylo, multiphylo) %>% 
    setNames(c("x", "y")) %>%
    future_pmap_dbl(ape::dist.topo)

  n <- length(multiphylo)
  dim(dists) <- c(n, n)

  as.dist(dists)
}
```

#### Result

```
> dist.topo4(trees)
  1 2 3
2 4    
3 4 2  
4 4 4 2
```